# Unity-Objects under background canvas

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

Okay basically I have two canvas's one which is my menu canvas (which is not the problem ) the other is my background canvas (which is ) I have objects that moves in and out of my 2d game but some of them goes behind my background canvas. I tried playing with the order in layer with my objects but it still does the same . I also tried tampering with the order in layer on the background canvas but it didn't work either. Another thing I tried was the render mode; I set it to screen space camera and put the main camera in the render camera and set the plane distance to 100 ; when I tried messing around with the plane distance (whist playing my game) all that happen was my background disappeared below: -0.3 and so on . It also disappeared above: 1005.03 and so on. Most of my objects appeared when I was messing around with the plane distance. How would I get all of my objects to appear above my background canvas? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your code blocks for what you have written and more contextual information. It's impossible to answer this question in its current state.

Comment: I'm sorry  what more contextual information do you need?  And would you like the code for my background canvas or anything else, because I'm not sure what specific code you need.  Thank you for answering so quickly